# Problem with writing method to shift elements in array by Array.Copy method. My solution is not good enough

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, copy

Task - Implement the Shift method using for statements, array indices and Array.Copy method for copying array elements. The method has two arguments. The source arguments has the array of integers to shift and return. Do not create a new array. The iterations argument has the array of integers. Each value in the iterations array is a shift instruction that tells the number of shift iterations. The odd elements (an element with odd index) tells the number of right shift iterations. The even elements (an element with even index or zero index) tells the number of left shift iterations. The first and the last elements in the source array should be wrapped to the other side of the array.

I have a problem with copying the elements more than one times.

My solution so far:

```
    public static int[] Shift(int[]? source, int[]? iterations)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        if (iterations == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iterations));
        }

        if (source == Array.Empty<int>())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        foreach (var currentIteration in iterations)
        {
            if (currentIteration == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (currentIteration % 2 == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < currentIteration; i++)
                {
                    var temp = source[0];
                    Array.Copy(source, 0, source, 1, source.Length - 1);
                    source[source.Length - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < currentIteration; i++)
                {
                    var temp = source[source.Length - 1];
                    Array.Copy(source, 1, source, 0, source.Length - 1);
                    source[0] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        return source;
    }
```

There are unit tests, which can be helpful in finding a solution.

```
    [TestCase(new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2, 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2, 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2, 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new int[] { }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 0 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 0, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 0, 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 0, 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 0, 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 1, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 1, 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 1, 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 1, 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 2, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 2, 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 2, 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 2, 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 4, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 4, 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 4, 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 4, 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new int[] { }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 0 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 0, 0 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 0, 0, 0 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 0, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 1, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 1, 1, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 1, 2 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 2, 1 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 1 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 })]
    [TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, ExpectedResult = new[] { 4, 5, 1, 2, 3 })]
    public int[] Shift_SourceAndIterationsAreNotNull_ReturnsArrayWithShiftedElements(int[] source, int[] iterations)
    {
        return Shifter.Shift(source, iterations);
    }
```

I would be grateful, if someone can help me, or explain how to find the best code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discription the direction of movement is indicated via iterations elemente **index** NOT **value** as you made in your original code.

you made some logical errors within your original method:

- if odd index you should move right(based on description) not left.
- if even index you should move left(based on description) not right.

The method below have comments regarding lines you have issues in,
hopefully it would achieve your task.

```
public static int[] Shift(int[]? source, int[]? iterations)
            {
                if (source == null || iterations == null || source == Array.Empty<int>())
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    
                // use for loop instead of foreach due to ease access of index of each element
                // i => iteration index
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations.Length; i++)
                {
                    //----------------------------------------
                    // you have to check the state(odd or even) of each iteration index and not the iteration value itself.
                    //----------------------------------------
                    
                    // if no movments to do contineu to next loop iteration
                    if (iterations[i] == 0)
                        continue;
                    
    
                    // if even index  
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < iterations[i]; j++)
                        {
                            var temp = source[0];
                            // Array.Copy(source, 0, source, 1, source.Length - 1);
                            // Note you passed reversed arguments
                            Array.Copy(source, 1, source, 0, source.Length - 1);
    
                            source[source.Length - 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                    // if odd index
                    else
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < iterations[i]; j++)
                        {
                            var temp = source[source.Length - 1];
                            // Array.Copy(source, 1, source, 0, source.Length - 1);
                            // Note you passed reversed arguments
                            Array.Copy(source, 0, source, 1, source.Length - 1);
                            source[0] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                return source;
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you for your comment, i edited it :) hopefully it is more clear now.